# Dynamically update DNS zones and records correctly?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

Using Bind9 i wish to be able to update both zones and the records of the zones without interrupting the service, as in restarting.

I've used `nsupdate` to control the records but now I'm looking into the zones.

`rndc` got functionality to add zones but it breaks `nsupdate` as i've understood due to fileformat so it might not be an option. It does however offer the 'reconfig' option that updates new or deleted zones without restarting bind. So i'm thinking about writing a custom service that writes the zone information to the named.conf and then the template file in /zones/ with the records. Then it runs `rndc reconfigure` to update the zone and finally i can use `nsupdate` to change/update the records.

How does this solution sound, are there any better ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
rndc reload zone.com
```

Using zone as your domain So like if you had the following

```
zone "zone.com" { }
```

If you add a new zone a simple

```
rndc reload
```

Should gracefully load/delete a zone from the server also

Comment: Right so use that method instead of reconfigure? After using a script to add the actual data to named.conf and a template to /zones/ ? Do my other steps sound reasonable? I'm just thinking of security, i want to be able to control the DNS from a custom admin panel.

Comment: if you add/delete a whole zone.. just use reload.. if you edit a zone use reload with the zonename after it. I do all our changes from puppet and that's how we gracefully handle changes with no downtime